# c# Web API - Re-post file upload to backend service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to re-post a file upload request from one Web API service to another backend API service.

Code is something like:

```
// exposed public API:

[HttpPost]

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadImage()
{

            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(backendAddress + "api/file/upload",
                Request.Content  // this is the incoming HttpRequestMessage.Content which appears intact with the file
            );


        // throws a 500 error before getting to the backend service


...

// private backend API

[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadImage()
{
    try
    {
        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

...
```

The reason I'm doing this is so the frontend boxes communicate with the clients and the backend box writes to the DB.

Comment: Have you tested connectivity to the backend service from your proxy server?

Comment: Yep - if I create a Get action it's called without issue and if I wrap the call to the POST with a 'using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())', the backed api gets invoked but throws an error saying unexpected end of file/data

Comment: It sounds like one of the async task may be returning too soon... Such as getting a response but not waiting for the data. I don't know if this will help of even the problem but see if adjusting the synchronization with ConfigureAwait(false) helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but that didn't work.  Weird though - it's now working using: await client.PostAsync(backend, Request.Content) and no changes to the backend action